# Negation the functionality of the function

Tags: javascript

I im quite confused in the negation of the functionality of my function. The original function takes 9 elements starting at nth index and decrease their transform position.

```
 function pushIt(max, target, index, count) {

   if (count == max ||  count == img.children  ) {
      running = false;
     return;
   }

   var tmp              = target[index];
   var matrix           = window.getComputedStyle(tmp).getPropertyValue("transform");
   var translate_left   = matrix.split(",")[4];
   var translate_top    = matrix.split(",")[5].split(")")[0]-215;
   tmp.style.transform  = "translate3d(" + translate_left + "px," + translate_top + "px,0)";
   setTimeout(function(){
    pushIt( max, target, index + 1, count + 1 );
   },50)
 }
```

What i wanted to do is to negate its functionality , e.g it wont decrease but increase transform position of (nth * 3) - 1 element ( counting down 9 elements )

```
function pushItDOWN(max, target, index  , count) {

   if ( count == max || index < 0 ) {
      running = false;
     return;
   }
     console.log("down");
   var tmp                  = target[index];
   var matrix               = window.getComputedStyle(tmp).getPropertyValue("transform");
   var translate_left       = matrix.split(",")[4];
   var  translate_top       = matrix.split(",")[5].split(")")[0]+215;
   tmp.style.transform      = "translate3d(" + translate_left + "px," + translate_top + "px,0)";
   setTimeout(function(){
    pushItDOWN(max, target, index - 1, count + 1 );
   },50)
 } 
}
```

What second function does is takes elements and set their transform to oblivion (e.g out of viewport) and somehow break the functionality of first function.

Did i overlook some key fact that is causing the problem , i seem to fail to find the root of the problem.
Live [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/chaLdjxz/9/) for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but most likely this is your error:

This will result in a string:

```
matrix.split(",")[5].split(")")[0]
```

Lets say it is `"500"`, then

```
matrix.split(",")[5].split(")")[0] + 215
// equals
"500" + 215
// results in (because + is both used as string concatenation as addition)
"500215"
// - will work, because it only has one meaning 
"500" - 215 // results in 285
```

Parse the value as an int (or float if necessary) before adding the 215:

```
parseInt(matrix.split(",")[5].split(")")[0]) + 215
```